# How to access some specific elements of a string array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have some string:

```
String[] Sorted = new String[len];
```

and I want to do:

```
return
```

for **n** elements, whether from the beginning, middle or end.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Best way is to start writing a program to do so.

Comment: Canyou clarify? Do you want to return an element or a sub-array?

Comment: I have no idea what you want tbh... can you show code or explain in more details ? or at least draw up logic ?

Comment: @AnubianNoob it is a sub array with **n** elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)`

will create a sub-array for you.

Answer (score 0):

startVal is the starting value and n is the number of values to copy.

Keep in mind that this will construct a new array and copies elements over. It's not very efficient, so if you're using it a lot you may notice performance issues. That said, it's usually ok.

```
return Arrays.copyOfRange(Sorted, startVal, n);
```

Comment: I do not want nth element. I want n elements.

Comment: It would be a sub-array of n-elements.

Comment: Well, this is the problem with copy procedure. It constructs a new array and the sub-part of the original array is no more there. Anyways thanks for the correction.

Comment: @tod Can you elaborate on what you mean? What's the problem with this?

Comment: After return, I want to operate on that sub-array part and expect that  my original array has this update. Please note that in my implementation the range will not be known initially.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the original array?

Comment: And how will you get a sub array if you don't know the range you want?

Comment: it will be calculated based upon parameters inside the function returning the sub-array

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the string array, if the item you are at is the one you want save the index and return the value. if n is the number of elements you want, then that saved index will give it to you, it is the starting position of the sub array, adding n-1 will give you then end of the subarray.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i think your trying to do this will solve that though

```
-You are able to take any string and say string.toCharArray
-This just converts The string which technically is always a string of char's(Array of chars) 
-to store this i would create a init a char array public char[] stringOfChars;
- stringOfChars  = <String variable>.toCharArray;
```

Comment: Think about another what I said about the string always being an array of char's...maybe you can access its elements from the string variable directly without pushing it into a char array

Answer (score -1):

you can create another array of String with the n elements which u want in that new array and then return that array.

Comment: That would be horribly inefficient. You should use System.arrayCopy(), which is what Arrays.copyOfRange() uses.